# Is it possible to archive WAL files for one PostgreSQL database within a single instance or must I create a second instance?

Tags: postgresql

I run a couple of PostgreSQL databases (9.3), one of which does not need archiving the other of which I'd rather run in WAL archive mode by can get away with not.

I now have a need for a data which is archived.

As far as I can tell the setting is on an instance basis, so I wouldn't be able to just choose which databases to archive and which not, which would indicate that I will need to create a new PostgreSQL instance.

Am I missing something?

Also, FWIW, will I be able to create database links between databases on the two instances?

Thanks,  --sw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot to choose database for archiving - only all (or none) in PostgreSQL instance can be archived. There are not any pother possibility now.

You can send query to other PostgreSQL instance via [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) extension or with [Foreign Data Wrappers API](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html). FDW API should be preferred, although dblink has some usage still.